# HTTPModule and Sharepoint Site

Tags: sharepoint, httpmodule, wspbuilder, ihttpmodule

I am running into an issue with using a HTTPModule with a sharepoint deployed site. Here is what I have:

- my asp.net pages inside the /layouts/[ProjectName]/ folder. The aspx file uses a sharepoint masterpage
- i have a HTTPModule and implments IHTTPModule
- the web.config contains 
  {httpModules}
    {add name="HTTPModule" type="HTTPModule, [fullname assembly]WebForms, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=370ae5aba0a4672a"/}
  {/httpModules}
- The web.config is placed layouts/[projectname] folder.

But for whatever reason, it looks like the HTTPModule doesn't get picked up. 
I've verified that:

- the assembly exists in GAC and the publickeytoken and all the stuff is correct.
- the GAC'ed assembly does contain the code for HTTPModule
- web.config is being picked from the layouts folder.
- httpmodule isn't being picked (i am throwing exception in the init, session start to have it break on me... but it doesn't throw those exceptions)

Is there some reason the HTTPModule isn't being picked up.

p.s: I am basically trying to do this http://vspug.com/dwise/2007/01/08/one-master-to-rule-them-all-two-actually/

Answer (score 1):

The web.config file that you need to update is the one located in the web application directory (IIS directory).

Answer (score 0):

If you’re running IIS 7.x in integrated mode, you use the  section shown here instead:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
...
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<modules>
...
</modules>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```